# sql: ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

I am running and keep getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

I have  had other errors with senmcolons, commas and other small mistakes, but this one is eating me alive

```
-- 1 - Create Faculty Table
create table Faculty (
FacultyID int not null primary key,
FirstName varchar(50) not null,
LastName varchar(50) not null,
Email varchar(50) not null,
Date_of_birth date,
Number_of_courses smallint not null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have auto-increment for `FacultyID` and it is inserting 0 for each record and you are getting

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Insert value for `FacultyID` or use Auto increment (AUTO_INCREMENT) for `FacultyID`.

```
create table Faculty (
    FacultyID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT  primary key,
    FirstName varchar(50) not null,
    LastName varchar(50) not null,
    Email varchar(50) not null,
    Date_of_birth date,
    Number_of_courses smallint not null
);
```

Comment: I added AUTO_INCREMENT but still giving me error    -> (9,4,2008),
    -> (9,5,2006);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql> 
mysql> -- number 5  - update all courses to four credits
mysql> update Courses set Number_of_credits = 4;  Is there a way to attach my code file?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `PRIMARY KEY` column name.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE dogs (dog_id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT), (breed VARCHAR(100), age INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `PRIMARY KEY` column name.
Example :

```
CREATE TABLE dogs ( dog_id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT), (breed VARCHAR(100), age INT);           
INSERT INTO dogs ( breed, age ) VALUES ( 'labrador', 4), ('pug', 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use this kind of insert:

insert into Faculty (FirstName , LastName, Email, Date_of_birth, Number_of_courses) values ('Name1','Lastname2','xx@gmail.com','2016-12-07',2);

You need to specify which column you are inserting.